# How to split decimal

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to split decimal to alert(

```
cm = 14*2.55;
outputCMVal = Math.round(cm*10)/10;
alert(outputCMVal); //35.7

arrDecimal = outputCMVal.split('.');
alert(arrDecimal[1]); //want to alert 7 from outputCMVal
```

http://jsfiddle.net/iwebsmile/2Lenx3es/

Comment: There really isn't a question here.  Can you explain what it is you would like to achieve?

Answer (score 3):

[split() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) is a member of string. Since `outputCMVal` is a number, you need to call `.toString()` method before `.split('.')`

```
arrDecimal = outputCMVal.toString().split('.');
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/91m6kmqw/

Comment: thanks, but doesn't work with `123.00` decimal number

Answer (score 0):

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RokoCB/2Lenx3es/3/)

Concatenate it to String before splitting by Character `.`

```
var cm = 14*2.55;
var outputCMVal = Math.round(cm*10)/10;
alert(outputCMVal);                              // 35.7

var arrDecimal = (outputCMVal+"").split('.');    
alert(arrDecimal[1]);                            // 7
```

also assign your `var`